# Freeing memory from dynamically created 2d char array

Tags: arrays, c, memory, free

Below is how i declare my array

```
const int SIZE = 128;
char line[SIZE];
char **lineArray = NULL;
char **lineArray = malloc(count * sizeof(char*));
                
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    lineArray[i] = (char *)malloc(SIZE* sizeof(char*));
}
```

Below here is where i try clear it...

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
{
    free(lineArray[i]); <<- program dies here
}
free(lineArray);
```

I of course looked at some of the other questions with same problem and i thought i might have been failing to use strcopy at some instances but nope. looks all above board

`strcpy(*(lineArray+i), line);` is only time i write to it.

Not much, honestly, I only learned about pointers and a bunch of other stuff this week, Ive gone over my lecture videos and it has honestly been less then useless.

Comment: Error: Multiple declarations of `lineArray`.

Comment: `malloc(SIZE* sizeof(char*)` ===> `malloc (SIZE);`

Comment: 1) Don't cast `malloc()`, but do check its return value. It returns `NULL` to indicate failure. 2) What is `count`? 3) What goes on in between the calls to `malloc()` and `free()`? Kindly provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: `strcpy(*(lineArray+i), line);` copies from `line`. What if `line` does not contain a valid string?

Comment: Once you fix the compiler errors in this (count variable missing, line array declared twice), this already works (some code smells aside): https://godbolt.org/z/1scc4ba8G . Therefore, as always, please try to provide a minimal, *reproducable* example of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not cast the result of `malloc` if your code does not compile it means that you are compiling the C code using C++ compiler and it is incorrect.
2. `char **lineArray` is not a 2D array only pointer to pointer. To allocate 2D array you need to use a `pointer to array`
3. `const int SIZE = 128;` is not a constant expression and your `line` will be a VLA which is not supported by all compilers (for example msvc does not support it )
4. Use the correct type for sizes. It is `size_t` not `int`

```
#define  SIZE 128

int main(void)
{
    size_t count;

    count = getcount();

    char (*lineArray)[SIZE] = malloc(count * sizeof(*lineArray));

    if(lineArray)
    {
        //do something with the 2D char array
    }

    free(lineArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that C operates at a very low level. You are not really working with arrays as known from other programming languages. There they might rather to be understood as lists.

In C, look at it more from an assembler perspective. Every array in C is basically nothing else than a pointer. If you use the square brackets, you specify the offset relative to this pointer. All you do is calculating new memory addresses:

```c
    char myArray[12];
    
    /*
     * Points to the start of the Array.
     */
    
    char *arrayStart = myArray;
    
    /*
     * Points to the 10th element in the array, which is the
     * same as myArray[10].
     */
     
    char *elem10 = arrayStart + 10 * sizeof(char);
```

So what you want to accomplish here is not really the implementation of a 2-dimensional array, but an array full of pointers to other memory locations. Each of these memory locations can be of any size, if they exist at all.

I'll give you two examples:

#### The dynamic way (no 2D-Array)

If I wanted to do the same thing as you, here's what I would do. This is not a 2D array! It is a pointer to an array of pointers. So you reserve memory that can contain these pointers, but they might not exist at all.

```c
    const int lineCount = 20;
    const int lineSize = 128;
    
    /*
     * Instead of malloc, which only allocates a block of memory,
     * I use calloc, since it also initializes this memory space.
     * 
     * The following code creates an array of pointers to char
     * arrays. Every item is automatically set to 0.
     *
     * Since all *alloc functions return 0 when the allocation fails,
     * which is conveniently also the value for 'false', you can do
     * a simple if check.
     */
    
    char **lines = (char**)calloc(lineCount, sizeof(char*));
    
    if (!lines)
        perror("Unable to allocate space for the line array.");
    
    /*
     * The next step would be to initialize the actual line buffers.
     * Notice that the pointers to the line buffers will automatically
     * be set to 0, if the allocation fails.
     */
     
    for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < lineCount; lineIndex++)
        lines[lineIndex] = (char*)calloc(lineSize, sizeof(char));
      
    /*
     * Now we free everything: First we free eacht line, then the
     * lineBuffer itself.
     */
     
    for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < lineCount; lineIndex++)
        free(lines[lineIndex]);
        
    free(lines);
```

#### The static way (2D-Array)

A 2D array can be thought of as a table. There is a fixed number of rows and columns. This is also the difference to your implementation. When you deal with pointers to pointers, there is a fixed number of rows, but the number of columns per row is arbitrary. Implementing a 'real' 2D array, can be done as follows:

```c
    const int lineCount = 20;
    const int lineSize = 128;
    
    /*
     * Allocate the total space for the array.
     * Its size will never change. Every line will have 128 chars.
     */
     
    char *array = (char*)calloc(lineCount * lineSize, sizeof(char));
    
    if (!array)
        perror("Unable to allocate space for the array.");
    
    /*
     * Let's say we want to select the 12th element in the 3rd line.
     * We have to calculate the offset relativ to the start of the
     * array (since it is also just a pointer). 
     *
     * This is actually the same thing the compiler does, when 
     * dealing with double indices as in array[row][col].
     */
    
    int line = 3;
    int element = 12;
    
    array[(line * lineSize) + element] = 'a';
    
    /*
     * Since the array is one solid block, we can free everything
     * at once.
     */
    
    free(array);
```

#### Which way is better?

It all depends on the complexity of the work you do with it. There are situations in which you have to rely on variable lengths. However, each *alloc call generates a certain overhead. Memory management in large environments is anything but trivial, so you try to keep the amount of reservations rather small. Typically, you reserve large blocks of contiguous memory and fetch more as needed. Just compare the two examples above, and you'll see there's significantly less to do and consider when working with a single reservation.

Managing the memory in a finely granulated way has its advantages, of course. You can be extremely efficient with limited resources, but it also increases complexity.